# Laravel No Message Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel

When i edit my projects it give me this error . please help . im stuck. how do i know where is the error. then maybe i can fix it.

This is my edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div style="width:100%" align="center">
<h1>Газар албаны нэр солих</h1>
<div style="background: white; width: 750px">
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('projects.edit',[$project->id]) }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
@if($companies != null)
<label for="company-content">Боловсруулсан газар албадын нэр</label>
<div class="form-group">
<select name="company_id" class="form-control" required> 
@foreach($companies as $company)
<option value="{{$company->name}}"> {{$company->name}} </option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif
@if($positions != null)
<div class="form-group">
<label for="position-content">Боловсруулсан хүний албан тушаал</label>
<select name="position_id" class="form-control" required> 
@foreach($positions as $position)
<option value="{{$position->name}}"> {{$position->name}} </option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif
<div class="form-group">
<label for="project-bner">Боловсруулсан хүний нэр<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input placeholder="Боловсруулсан хүний нэр" id="project-bner" name="bner" spellcheck="false" class="form-control" required/>
</div>
@if($positions != null)
<div class="form-group">
<label for="position-content">Хянасан хүний албан тушаал</label>
<select name="poz_id" class="form-control" required> 
@foreach($positions as $position)
<option value="{{$position->name}}"> {{$position->name}} </option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif
<div class="form-group">
<label for="project-hner">Хянасан хүний нэр<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input placeholder="Хянасан хүний нэр" id="project-hner" required name="hner" spellcheck="false" class="form-control"/></div>
@if($documents != null)
<div class="form-group">
<label for="document-content">Баримт бичгийн төрөл</label>
<select name="document_id" class="form-control" required> 
@foreach($documents as $document)
<option value="{{$document->name}}"> {{$document->name}} </option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
@endif
<div class="form-group">
<label for="project-bbner">Баримт бичгийн нэр<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input placeholder="Баримт бичгийн нэр" id="project-bbner" required name="bbner" spellcheck="false" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<label for="ddate">Дугаар өгсөн огноо</label>
{{ Form::date('ddate', new \DateTime(), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="project-bdugaar">Баримт бичгийн дугаар<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input placeholder="Баримт бичгийн дугаар" id="project-bdugaar" required name="bdugaar" spellcheck="false" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="batalgaatdate">Баталгаат хугацаа</label>
<select class="form-control" id="ddate" name="batalgaatdate" required>
<option value="Хуулийн төсөл - / 40 хоног хүртэл /">Хуулийн төсөл - / 40 хоног хүртэл /</option>
<option value="УИХ-ын болон ЗГ-ын тогтоолын төсөл - / 20 хоног хүртэл /">УИХ-ын болон ЗГ-ын тогтоолын төсөл - / 20 хоног хүртэл /</option>
<option value="Зөвлөмж - / 10 хоног хүртэл /">Зөвлөмж - / 10 хоног хүртэл /</option>
<option value="Журам - / 21 хоног хүртэл /">Журам - / 21 хоног хүртэл /</option>
<option value="Дүрэм - / 21 хоног хүртэл /">Дүрэм - / 21 хоног хүртэл /</option>
<option value="Заавар - / 10 хоног хүртэл /">Заавар - / 10 хоног хүртэл /</option>
<option value="Ажлын заавар - / 10 хоног хүртэл /">Ажлын заавар - / 10 хоног хүртэл /</option>
<option value="Удирдамж - / 5 хоног хүртэл /">Удирдамж - / 5 хоног хүртэл /</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="version">Хувилбар</label>
<select class="form-control" id="version" name="version" required>
<option value="Шинэ">Шинэ</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="burtgel">Анхан шатны бүртгэлтэй эсэх</label>
<select class="form-control" id="burtgel" name="burtgel" required>
<option value="Тийм">Тийм</option>
<option value="Үгүй">Үгүй</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="project-aner">АШБ-ын нэр<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input placeholder="АШБ-ын нэр" id="project-aner" required name="aner" spellcheck="false" class="form-control"/></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="project-adugaar">АШБ-ын дугаар<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input placeholder="АШБ-ын дугаар" id="project-adugaar" required name="adugaar" spellcheck="false" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="batlagdsan">Батлагдсан эсэх</label>
<select class="form-control" id="batlagdsan" name="batlagdsan" required>
<option value="Тийм">Тийм</option>
<option value="Үгүй">Үгүй</option>
</select>
</div>
<label for="batdate">Батлагдсан огноо</label>
{{ Form::date('batdate', new \DateTime(), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="project-btushaal">Батлагдсан тушаалын тоот<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input   placeholder="Батлагдсан тушаалын тоот" id="project-btushaal" required name="btushaal" spellcheck="false" class="form-control"/></div>
<label for="date">ББНС-д хүлээн авсан огноо</label>
{{ Form::date('date', new \DateTime(), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</br>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

@endsection
ProjectController

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
 {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'company_id' => 'required',
        'position_id' =>  'required',
        'bner' =>  'required',
        'poz_id' =>  'required',
        'hner' =>  'required',
        'document_id' =>  'required',
        'bbner' =>  'required',
        'ddate' =>  'required',
        'bdugaar' =>  'required',
        'batalgaatdate' =>  'required',
        'version' =>  'required',
        'burtgel' =>  'required',
        'aner' => 'required',
        'adugaar' => 'required',
        'batlagdsan' =>  'required',
        'batdate' => 'required',
        'btushaal' =>  'required',
        'date' =>  'required',
    ]);
        $postData = $request->all();
        Post::find($id)->update($postData);
        Session::flash('success_msg', 'Project updated successfully!');
        return redirect()->route('projects.index');
 }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/projects/edit/{id}','ProjectsController@edit')->name('projects.edit');
```

It looks like your post mostly code please add details and i adding some details here It looks like your post mostly code please add details and i adding some details here It looks like your post mostly code please add details and i adding some details here It looks like your post mostly code please add details and i adding some details here

[image: This is the error message]

[image: 2]

Comment: `Route::get` needs to be `Route::post`. 405 exceptions mean the wrong HTTP verb is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect. Request should always be the first parameter:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Edit:

If you are submitting a form to the server, you should be `POST`ing to `update`. If you are navigating to the form, you should be `GET`ing from `edit`.

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="<?php echo e(route('projects.edit',[$project->id])); ?>">`

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\ISO-doc\resources\views\projects\edit.blade.php)`

Comment: Don't use an array, just pass the Id.  Request is automatically injected into the method as the first parameter.

Comment: i'm sorry sir. me English is not good. do i have to change my View Name ? like this?  `projects/update.blade.php`?

Comment: No the route needs to change. `(route('projects.update',[$project->id]))`

Comment: Now no message error sir.  my other view's edit working as well. and projects/edit its not working im shocked

Comment: Did you remove the array from the route? Like this: `route('projects.update',$project->id)`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `get` route in your web.php but you are trying to send the form via a `POST` request.

**Change:**

```
Route::get('/projects/edit/{id}','ProjectsController@edit')->name('projects.edit');
```

**To:**

```
Route::post('/projects/edit/{id}','ProjectsController@edit')->name('projects.edit');
```

And you route name is wrong,

**Change your Form action to**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('projects.edit',[$project->id]) }}">
```

Comment: same sir .     `protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }`

Comment: its same sir . `REQUEST_METHOD  

"POST"`

Comment: `method="POST"` doesnt make any difference, its case insensitive.

Comment: @btl yeah sorry my bad

Comment: Route::post('/projects/edit','ProjectsController@edit')->name('projects.edit'); without id, and take it from post Request: $request->input('id'), not GET param

Comment: @SapneshNaik now check it out sir

Comment: @М.Билгүүн change all occurances of  `$var != null`  in your if conditons to `!empty($var)`. Because a collection might not be null and still be empty which causes the `trying to get property of non object` error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a post request on a get route. So change the route from:

```
Route::get('/projects/edit/{id}','ProjectsController@edit')->name('projects.edit');
```

to

```
Route::post('/projects/edit/{id}','ProjectsController@edit')->name('projects.update');
```

Comment: same sir . `protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others) { throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others); }`

Comment: @М.Билгүүн change name of the route aswell at the end